# pandas adjust strings when joining columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to create a joined column, but do not know how to adjust
the strings.
I need the names to be right adjusted. Padding did not work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Family":['Antares','Delta','Atlas','Falcon'],
                    "Launches":[1,1,4,11]})

df['Family'] =  df['Family']  + '   ' + df['Launches'].astype(str)  

        Family  Launches        
0  Antares   1         1        
1    Delta   1         1      
2    Atlas   4         4      
3  Falcon   11        11  

I want the output to look like this   

        Family  Launches        
0 Antares    1         1        
1   Delta    1         1      
2   Atlas    4         4      
3  Falcon   11        11
```

Comment: Can you show us the expected output? Do you mean you want the strings to be justified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still can using `pad`

```
df.Family.str.pad(df.Family.str.len().max(),side = 'left',fillchar = ' ')+ '   ' + df['Launches'].astype(str).str.pad(df['Launches'].astype(str).str.len().max(),side = 'left',fillchar = ' ')

Out[474]: 
0    Antares    1
1      Delta    1
2      Atlas    4
3     Falcon   11
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, use `.str.rjust`:

```
df['Family'] = (df['Family'] + ' ' + 
               df['Launches'].astype(str).str
                             .rjust(df['Launches'].astype(str)
                                                  .str.len().max(),' '))
```

Output:

```
0    Antares  1
1      Delta  1
2      Atlas  4
3     Falcon 11
dtype: object
```